# merge tags: tab and tabs

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

Very recently a new tag "tabs" was created.

From the one linked question, it looks like it could have been tagged "tab".

Maybe "tabs" should be merged with "tab"?

Comment: shouldn't use plurals, but 'tabs' more meaningful .. So +1 for 'tabs' to supersede 'tab'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, good idea -- I merged them. We generally prefer the plural form of a tag unless there is some compelling reason to use the singular version.